# How to replace double tabs with single tabs using pipes?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I need to replace all consecutive tabs in a bytestring with single tabs, like so:

```
"___\t___\t\t___\t\t\t___"
```

becomes

```
"___\t___\t___\t___"
```

I have *no* idea how to do it.

After half an hour of figuring stuff out I managed to replace the first occurrence of double tabs, like so (and even this is actually wrong – it adds a tab to an empty string):

```
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

removeConsecutiveTabs =
  PB.break (== tab) . mapped %~ \p -> do
    yield (B.singleton tab)
    PB.dropWhile (== tab) p
```

However, I still don't know how to replace all occurrences of consecutive tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import           Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Control.Lens hiding (each)

cleanTabs p = do
  p1 <- view (PB.span (/= 9)) p
  x <- lift $ next p1
  case x of
    Left r -> return r
    Right (a, p2) -> do
      yield "\t"
      let p3 = PB.dropWhile (== 9) (yield a >> p2)
      cleanTabs p3

source :: Monad m => Producer ByteString m ()
source = each [ "this", "is\t an", "\t\texample\t", "\t.", "\t\tmiddle\t", "\there"]

example = do
  putStrLn $ "input: " ++ (show $ P.toList source)
  putStrLn $ "output:" ++ (show $ P.toList (cleanTabs source))
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is operating on a stream of bytes rather than one of bytestring chunks. That can be done through `pack` from pipes-bytestring (and pipes-text). Here is a not particularly sophisticated demo:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Control.Monad
import Control.Lens (over)

test byst = runEffect $
    removingConsecutiveTabs (PB.fromLazy byst) >-> PB.stdout

removingConsecutiveTabs :: Monad m
                        => Producer B.ByteString m r
                        -> Producer B.ByteString m r
removingConsecutiveTabs = over PB.pack tabGatekeeper

tabGatekeeper :: Monad m => Producer PB.Word8 m r -> Producer PB.Word8 m r
tabGatekeeper = go False
    where
    go wasTab stream = do
        ex <- lift $ next stream
        case ex of
            Left r -> return r
            Right (x, stream') -> do
                let thisIsATab = w8IsTab x
                unless (wasTab && thisIsATab) $ yield x
                go thisIsATab stream'

    w8IsTab x = toEnum (fromIntegral x) == '\t'
```

```
GHCi> :set -XOverloadedStrings
GHCi> test "___\t___\t\t___\t\t\t___\n"
___ ___ ___ ___
```

Comment: It seems that the focus of the library is more on parsing from streams than on manipulating them.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `view` with both `pack` and `unpack` I think you can just pick one and use it as a function (or maybe with some idiomatic identity function from `lens`).

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed, all you need is `over`. Looks obvious in hindsight :) Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Now I'm wondering if this can be cleaned up a bit using `StateT` to handle the `wasTab`. I don't know how monad transformers and pipes get along. You could certainly run the effect in the transformed monad; I'm not sure if there's a nicer approach available.

Comment: @dfeuer I thought about `StateT` too, but I don't think it would feel natural in practice. You'd either have to carry a single-purpose `StateT` layer around or run the pipe to completion earlier than intended to get rid of it.

Comment: What would go wrong using `flip evalStateT False . runEffect`, aside from failing to separate concerns?

Comment: @dfeuer Nothing would break, but the concern separation failure would be ugly. `runEffectT` is the final step used to run what can be a complex pipeline, all stages of which would now be in some manner aware of a state which only matters to that one tab-filtering function.

Comment: That makes me wonder if there is or could be a function that takes a pipe over `StateT m` and an initial state and manufactures a pipe over `m`.

Comment: @dfeuer sure, see `runStateP` in `Pipes.Lift`

Comment: @Artyom, I just opened a request to add such functionality to `machines`. I didn't have a good name for it though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which doesn't use `PB.break` but just uses basic pipe operations. One of the problem is that the data comes in chunks, and you have to keep track of whether or not the last chunk ended in a tab or not:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Lib5
where

import Pipes
import Pipes.ByteString
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Control.Monad

printAll = forever $ do a <- await; lift $ putStrLn $ "got: " ++ show a

endsWith bs ch = BS.length bs > 0 && BS.last bs == ch

convertDoubleTabs = await >>= go0

-- no precediing tab
go0 b = do
  let (pre,post) = BS.breakSubstring "\t\t" b
  yield pre
  if BS.length post == 0
    then if endsWith pre '\t'
            then await >>= go1
            else await >>= go0
    else do yield "\t"
            go0 (BS.drop 2 post)

-- last chunk ended in a tab
go1 b = do
  if BS.length b == 0
    then await >>= go1
    else if BS.index b 0 == '\t'
            then go0 (BS.drop 1 b)
            else go0 b

example1 = runEffect $ each [ "this", "is\t an", "\t\texample\t", "\t."] 
                       >-> convertDoubleTabs
                       >-> printAll
```

I'll add to this answer if I figure out a solution using the `Pipes.ByteString` and lenses.

To convert all consecutive tabs:

```
convertTabs = await >>= go0
  where
    go0 b = do
      let (pre,post) = BS.break (== '\t') b
      yield pre
      if BS.length post == 0
        then await >>= go0
        else do yield "\t"
                go1 post

    go1 b = do
      let b' = BS.dropWhile (== '\t') b
      if BS.null b'
        then await >>= go1
        else go0 b'

example2 = runEffect $ each [ "___\t___\t\t___\t\t\t___" ]
                       >-> convertTabs
                       >-> printAll
```

Comment: I just noticed my code only replaces double-tabs with single tabs - not all consecutive tabs.

Comment: yeah, I meant consecutive tabs. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: The whole point of the library is to give ways of working with sources of byte strings as though they were sources of bytes, without worrying about chunks!

Comment: @dfeuer I agree, and I feel that it should be possible to write a more idiomatic solution with combinators in `Pipes.ByteString`, yet I've no idea how to do it. Would you care to try your hand at a better solution? (It really feels like it should be obvious...)